# RecyclerView last Item does not show entirely the item, because of the above TabLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, recyclerview-layout

I have a `RecyclerView` that does not show the last item, I know there are a lot of similar posts, but is all the day I am trying to make changes without success in the file, I guess the main reason could be the `TabView` because without it, it works like a charm. The RecyclerView is called by the include below..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cardViewBackground">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/address_filter_tl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/primaryWhite"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/primaryWhite"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/inactiveTabText"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/search_results_tab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/search_result" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/address_book_tab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/address_book" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/my_location_cv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/search_results_cv"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/address_filter_tl">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/my_location_cl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/my_location_cl"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/my_location_cl"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/my_location_cl"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_my_location"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
                android:text="@string/my_location"
                android:textColor="@color/primaryBlack"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/my_location_address_tv"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/primaryGreyText"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
                tools:text="7331 GA Apeldoorn" />

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="36dp" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/search_results_cv"
        layout="@layout/addresses_card_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/my_location_cv" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/appCompatImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_goneMarginBottom="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/powered_by_google"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/search_results_cv"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is the include content layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/addresses_rv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/address_item" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: set your `layout_height` to `0dp`. for your `<include`

Comment: Please attach a screenshot too. It would be more easy to understand

Comment: I cannot attach screenshot sorry:( I apologise, but I can't, basically the last item is not fully visible and you have a view with the a tab layout and a small margin

Comment: @KaranMer the RecyclerView disappears if I set `0dp` in `<include` and the same if I do it inside `RecyclerView` I tried these things already

Comment: is there any special reason you are including your recyclerview in a separate layout? can't you just add it directly to your xml?

Comment: @Drocchio: while setting height to 0dp for include you also need to set constraintBottomToBottomofParent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your include xml as below, set `layout_height="0dp"` and also set bottom constraint for it. Check if it works.

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/search_results_cv"
        layout="@layout/addresses_card_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/my_location_cv"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

Comment: the problem is that now cannot see the widget below include

Comment: you will need to change your constraint bottom to top of view you have added.

Comment: mmh if  I set `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/appCompatImageView"` this last view appears on top because is constrained `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/search_results_cv"` and I am afraid my use case is quite complex

Comment: if its the last item in view, attach its constraint bottom to bottom of parent and remove top constraint.

Comment: does not work, the icon have to stay below the card view if recycler view is empty, and if is not the icon have to stay just below the recycler view(card view is invisible)

Comment: you might want to ask separate question with updated code.